# Changing credentials for shared drive

Tags: windows, samba, network-share

I am running a Samba (linux) server (for the sake of argument with IP address of 192.168.1.2) while the clients are all windows 10/11. There are 2 shared folders on this server \\192.168.1.2\bob and \\192.168.1.2\alice. The issue and the way to reproduce it is to map a network drive with alice/alicepassword credentials to a random network drive:

- net use X: \\192.168.1.2\alice /user:alice alicepassword /persistent:yes

this works as a charm and every time the system boots up, X: drive shows up without any authentication issue. But if I want to change the drive X to use \\192.168.1.2\bob with credentials bob/bobpassword, I do:

- net use X: /delete
- net use X: \\192.168.1.2\bob /user:bob bobpassword /persistent:yes

every time the system boots up the authentication seems to fail.

I have tried to clear credentials manager, or any mention of 192.168.1.2 from regedit but nothing seems to work. Attaching the network drive on boot keeps failing due to what looks like credential/authentication failure. A window pops up and it asks for the password for the user bob. Like it has something cached but that doesn't seem to work.